# razor pay is stuck when using with webview in xamarin android

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.android, razorpay

I am having a website with razor pay integration and its working fine with browsers.
Now I am loading the same website in a webview in xamarin android, but unfortunately its stuck on razor pay payment page.
I searched and tried different methods but didn't got succeed. [image: I am attaching the screen shot of the same.]

```
`WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webView.SetWebChromeClient(chrome);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
        webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(false);
        webView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
        webView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
        webView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        webView.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
        webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = (true);

        webView.LoadUrl(websiteurl);`
```

this is the code I am using.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the information you provided, it's hard to find what the problem is. Had you do this following the [official document](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/webview/#code-sample)?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've faced a similar issue before. What's probably happening here is that razorpay is opening the payment confirmation screen in a new "window", which isn't supported by WebView and you seem "stuck" on this screen because you can't access the payment confirmation screen.

I presume you are passing the `handler` function in the razorpay object. I would suggest you use `callback_url` instead. Here's the relevant doc: https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/callback-url/

Comment: How call_back url will help here? how response can be parsed inside the application incase of call_back